# collesce issue with mysql

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have a pretty flat table - tbl_values which has userids as well as netAmounts in a given row. In the example below, 2280 has no records in the past 30 days based on the timestamp.

I'd expect this to return 3 rows, with 2280 as "0" - but I'm only getting 2 back? Am I missing something obvious here?

```
SELECT userid, (COALESCE(SUM(netAmount),0)) as Sum FROM `tbl_values` where userid in (2280, 399, 2282) and date > (select DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)) GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always want to return the user, regardless of rather they have a matching record in `tbl_values`, what you're looking for is an `outer join`:

```
SELECT u.userid, COALESCE(SUM(v.netAmount),0) as Sum 
FROM (
    SELECT 2280 userid UNION ALL
    SELECT 399 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2282
) u 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_values` v ON u.userid = v.userid AND
        v.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day) 
GROUP BY u.userid
```

---

If you perhaps have a `Users` table, then you can use it instead of the subquery.

```
SELECT u.userid, COALESCE(SUM(v.netAmount),0) as Sum 
FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_values` v ON u.userid = v.userid AND
        v.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day) 
WHERE u.userid in (2280, 399, 2282)
GROUP BY u.userid
```

Comment: Second query weeks awesomely. If I want '0' instead of Null, I assume I could still do that with a case statement?

Comment: this works perfectly...SELECT u.userid, COALESCE(SUM(v.netAmount),0) as Sum 
FROM  tbl_user u 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_values` v ON u.userid = v.userid AND
        v.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day) 
WHERE u.userid in (2280, 399, 2282)
GROUP BY u.userid ORDER BY u.userid

Comment: @timw07 -- Glad I could help!  I edited the response since it does look like you wanted `Coalesce` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT userid, (COALESCE(SUM(netAmount),0)) as Sum
FROM `tbl_values`
where userid in (2280, 399, 2282) and
      date > (select DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))
GROUP BY userid;
```

The filter in the `where` clause finds no rows that match for user id 2280.  Assuming that at least one row exists somewhere, you can get what you want by moving the `date` comparison to a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT userid,
       sum(case when date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
                then netAmount else 0
           end) as Sum
FROM `tbl_values`
WHERE userid in (2280, 399, 2282)
GROUP BY userid;
```

EDIT:

If you really want all three results, then use a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.userid,
       coalesce(sum(netAmount), 0) as Sum
FROM  (select 2280 as userid union all
       select 399 union all
       select 2282
      ) u left join
      tbl_values t
      on u.userid = t.userid and
         t.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
GROUP BY u.userid;
```

Comment: Interesting, this is still only getting me 2 results now - but there is a 0 set appropriately for 2280. I'm digging further, could be something really simple :)